# OpenWRT BusyBox init does not create /etc/init.d/rcS

Tags: busybox, init, openwrt, sysvinit, busybox-init

I'm building an OpenWRT image (Chaos Calmer) that needs BusyBox to be configured to use `init`. So, in the busybox configuration, I enter the Init Utilities menu, then enable `init`, as well as support for reading an inittab file.

When my image finishes building, it contains the following `/etc/inittab` file:

```
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS S boot
::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcS K shutdown
::askconsole:/bin/ash --login
```

This looks fine to me, except that `/etc/init.d/rcS` does not exist. If I load this image onto the router, it obviously fails to boot with the following messages:

```
init started: BusyBox v1.23.2 (2019-08-29 09:26:36 CDT)
Bad inittab entry at line 3
can't run '/etc/init.d/rcS': No such file or directory
```

How should this be resolved? Am I supposed to add my own `/etc/init.d/rcS`? If so, how should that be done (i.e., as its own OpenWRT package)? Is there a standard/default rcS script I can use as a template? Is there a configuration option to include this file that I may have missed? And why does it think the inittab entry on line 3 is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

It is said , openWrt is using procd for init work. So there is no /etc/init.d/rcS anymore.

Comment: Where is it said, to verify your claim.